# How to get category value in orderable snippet

Tags: wagtail

I'm trying to make a wagtail routable page that filters snippets by category. Snippets can have multitple category. I can't figure out why when I try to get categories they are showing None on my page.

```
from django.db import models
from django.shortcuts import render

from modelcluster.models import ClusterableModel
from modelcluster.fields import ParentalKey
from wagtail.core.models import Page, Orderable
from wagtail.core.fields import RichTextField
from wagtail.admin.edit_handlers import (
FieldPanel, 
PageChooserPanel, 
MultiFieldPanel,
InlinePanel
)
from wagtail.images.edit_handlers import ImageChooserPanel
from wagtail.snippets.edit_handlers import SnippetChooserPanel
from wagtail.contrib.routable_page.models import RoutablePageMixin,
```

route
    from wagtail.snippets.models import register_snippet
    import uuid

class Resource(ClusterableModel):
    """Snippet for Resources"""

```
id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
resource_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=False, null=True)
phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=12, blank=True, null=True)
website = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
info = RichTextField(blank=True, null=True)

panels = [
    MultiFieldPanel(
        [
            FieldPanel("resource_name"),
            FieldPanel("phone_number"),
        ],
        heading="Resource information"
    ),
    MultiFieldPanel(
        [
            FieldPanel('website')
        ],
        heading="Links"
    ),
    MultiFieldPanel(
        [
            FieldPanel('info')
        ],
        heading="Info"
    ),
    MultiFieldPanel(
        [
            InlinePanel("category")
        ]
    )
]

def __str__(self):
    """String representation of this class"""
    return self.resource_name

class Meta:
    verbose_name = "Resource"
    verbose_name_plural = "Resources"

register_snippet(Resource)

class ResourceCatsOrderable(Orderable):
"""child category for multiple category choices"""

id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
resource = ParentalKey('home.Resource', related_name="category")
category = models.ForeignKey('home.ResourceCategory', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)

panels = [
    SnippetChooserPanel("category")
]


 class ResourceCategory(models.Model):
"""Snippet for Resources category"""

id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
category_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=False, null=True)

panels = [
    MultiFieldPanel(
        [
            FieldPanel('category_name')
        ],
        heading="Category"
    )
]

def __str__(self):
    """String representation of this class"""
    return self.category_name

class Meta:
    verbose_name = "Category"
    verbose_name_plural = "Categories"

register_snippet(ResourceCategory)

class HomePage(RoutablePageMixin, Page):
"""Home page model."""

template = "home/home_page.html"
max_count = 1

subtitle = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=True)
left_col = RichTextField()
right_col = RichTextField()

content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
    FieldPanel("subtitle"),
    FieldPanel("left_col"),
    FieldPanel("right_col")
]

class Meta:
    verbose_name = "Home Page"
    verbose_name_plural = "Home Pages"

@route(r'^resource/(?P<cat_slug>[-\w]+)/?$')
def resources_page(self, request, cat_slug, *args, **kwargs):
    context = self.get_context(request, *args, **kwargs)
    context['a_special_test'] = cat_slug
    resources = Resource.objects.all()
    print(resources)
    context['resources'] = resources


    return render(request, "home/resources_page.html", context)
```

My template to test:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}   
{% load wagtailcore_tags wagtailimages_tags %}

{% block content %}
<div class="content">
        <p>This is the resource page and it has this context {{a_special_test}}</p>
    {% for resource in resources %}
<p>
    <a href="{{ resource.website }}">
        {{ resource.resource_name }}
    </a>
</p>
<p>{{resource.category}}</p>
<p>{{resource.phone_number}}</p>
<div>{{resource.info | richtext}}</div>


{% endfor %}

</div>
```

On the page I get:

home.ResourceCatsOrderable.None

I can create Resources in the back end and the orderable snippet works and I can see mulitiple categories for the resources. How can I use filter and categories using snippets?

Answer (score 2):

I think there's some confusion here between registering a Django model as a snippet, ClusterableModels and Orderables.

You can create a Snippet from just about any model that [eventually] inherits from django's `Model` class.

```
@register_snippet
class Category(models.Model):
    """Category for snippet."""

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    # other fields 

    # add your panels and __str__
```

That's a basic snippet. They can get as complex as a Django model can.

Whereas an Orderable is essentially (an easy way to think of it) a Django InlineModel, but done the Wagtail way. There's some intricacies in there that are a bit irrelevant to this answer so I'll let it at that for now.

With an Orderable that needs to select a Snippet, it would look something along these lines:

```
class CategorySelectingOrderable(Orderable):
    """Category selecting orderable."""

    page = ParentalKey("home.HomePage", related_name="resources")
    category = models.ForeignKey("home.Category", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    panels = [
        SnippetChooserPanel("category")
    ]

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Resource"
        verbose_name_plural = "Resources"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category.name
```

And lastly on your HomePage, you'd use an InlinePanel to create the recurring Orderable interface in Wagtail.

```
class HomePage(Page):

    # Fields here 

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        MultiFieldPanel(
            [
                # Note that the first parameter is the same name as the related_name in the code block above
                InlinePanel("resources", label="Resource", min_num=1) 
            ],
            heading="Author(s)",
        ),
    ]
```

And in your template you'll be able to loop through them all with:

```
{% for resource in self.resources.all %}
    {{ resource.category.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

I know this can be a lot of code to take in at first, but it becomes second nature once you do it a couple times.

I also have a [YouTube video on Orderables](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qqcd72bcPmc&list=PLMQHMcNi6ocsS8Bfnuy_IDgJ4bHRRrvub&index=14&t=1s) and I also have a very relevant video on [using a SnippetChooserPanel to Select Multiple Blog Authors](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AZuyqG11hcE&list=PLMQHMcNi6ocsS8Bfnuy_IDgJ4bHRRrvub&index=22&t=1s) (but you'd use it for Resources instead of Blog Authors)

And of course there's always the [Wagtail Docs (Inline Models/Orderables)](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/latest/topics/pages.html#inline-models)

Comment: Thank you. Did I leave out that resources will be a routable page off of Home? I’m trying to build a filter that when you go to resources/<category>/ it will pull a filtered list of the resources snippets. Does that change your answer? I’m confused how to query for snippets using the category orderable

Comment: I'm trying to follow but I keep getting this message: AttributeError: type object 'ResourcePage' has no attribute 'resources'

Comment: I finally figured out I had to use the Orderable class to do my filtering. However, now the issue is that when I parse the value off of the url using a regex capture, it is lower case and my category is entered as upper case.